# Can I start my app after booting on Android API 30?

Tags: android, android-api-30

```
public class Starter extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Log.e("BOOT_CHECK", "Receiver Arrive_1");
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
Log.e("BOOT_CHECK", "Receiver Arrive_2");
Intent i = new Intent(context, NetworkCheckService.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
try {
pendingIntent.send();
Log.e("BOOT_CHECK", "pending : "+pendingIntent.toString());
Log.e("BOOT_CHECK", "Receiver Arrive_3");
} catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

        }
        Log.e("BOOT_CHECK", "Receiver Arrive_4");
    }

}
```

```
**Manifest.xml**
\<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" /\>
\<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" /\>
...
\<receiver android:name=".Starter"
android:enabled="true"
android:exported="false"
android:label="StartReceiver"\>
\<intent-filter\>
\<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /\>
\<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /\>
\</intent-filter\>
\</receiver\>
```

** When booting my app I Can Check my logs which in logcat, but it doesn't works **
and also when I changed the code like "startForegroundService" doesn't works

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that a BroadcastReceiver can't start a foreground service, and a background service will be killed in 2 minutes.  So what you're trying to do can't be done.  However, I question if you need to-  your service is called network check service.  If all you want to do is check if the network is up to do some work, JobScheduler is a better fit.

Comment: Oh thanks for Answer~ Ah it's just try for working test because 
                PendingIntent.getActivity     has same reaction  so your Idea need some delay before activce?

Comment: That won't work either-  a broadcast receiver can't launch anything in the foreground except under special circumstances:  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts

Comment: I see I see, oh it' works  when I changed getActivity and it's follow IntroActivity.class but it's need to run once just first time